# Patching a message from a shared inbox does not work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My use case is that I want to create an app which reads messages from a shared inbox and then I can assign a user to a message. To do that, I added a schemaExtension for Messages

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions
{
    "id":"message_responsibility",
    "description": "Sets a users email to a message to indicate a messages responsibility",
    "targetTypes": [
        "Message"
    ],
    "owner": "<redacted>",
    "properties": [
        {
            "name": "responsibility",
            "type": "String"
        },
    ]
}
```

After creating the schemaExtension, I made it available:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/schemaExtensions/{id}
{
    "status": "Available",
    "owner": "<redacted>",
}
```

Then I tried adding the responsibility to an existing message from the shared inbox:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('shared@inbox.com')/messages/<messageId>
{
    "extr5f2qmdk_responsibility": {
        "responsibility": "someone@inbox.com"
    }
}
```

But all I get is this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "73cc3cb2-37e4-4003-833b-b2348804c045",
            "date": "2018-11-28T10:50:36"
        }
    }
}
```

Even trying to include the property with a ?$select statement, will make return a server error 500:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('shared@inbox.com')/messages?$select=extr5f2qmdk_responsibility
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assume you want to create a schemaExtensions for the message resources.

Based on the error response you posted, you didn't have the right permission. From [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schemaextension-post-schemaextensions?view=graph-rest-1.0), the permission should be `Delegated (work or school account)     Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

Second, you have created a schemaExtensions with name `responsibility`, however, when you add a schema extension with name `extr5f2qmdk_responsibility`